# How can I change the title ckeditor sets for inline instances?

Tags: ckeditor

Right now it sets it to Rich text editor, element_id. Is there any way to change that?

Answer (score 3):

In ckeditor.js search for the following string:

```
a.changeAttr("title",c)
```

And justs set it to an empty string if you want:

```
a.changeAttr("title",'');
```

Keep In mind, you'll lose this during an update, but this is the only way until they add it to their editable configurations. Only use this if you don't mind losing some a11y.

Answer (score 0):

This title is set in [CKEDITOR.editable](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/editable.js#L934). You can change it by:

- modifying this code,
- changing translation in `lang/<your lang>.js` (e.g. https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/lang/en-gb.js#L30)

But when you'll modify it, remember that this title is there to provide a11y.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/14747609/250294 this feature will be possible when http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10042 is fixed.