# ckEditor 4.1 - How do I remove inline tooltip

Tags: ckeditor, tooltip

The behavior of the tooltip in the inline editor is so annoying while typing or moving cursor around. : How do I remove it or change the its behavior?

I want to show the image but have not enough reputation. :) http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/How-do-I-remove-the-inline-editor-tooltip

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the title ckeditor sets for inline instances?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502142/how-can-i-change-the-title-ckeditor-sets-for-inline-instances)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502142/how-can-i-change-the-title-ckeditor-sets-for-inline-instances/14548739

Answer (score 0):

apparently the ckeditor team didn't think this was important or easily achievable:

http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9896

Answer (score 0):

Don't give up, i think if you find the right element within the CKEDITOR iframe, you could disable it using JQuery.

You could always give it a go: 
[How to disable tooltip in the browser with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027762/how-to-disable-tooltip-in-the-browser-with-jquery)

Besides that it's not more than a title attribute to the editor.

Answer (score 0):

[This issue will be resolved in CKEditor 4.2](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10042). You can use proposed solution if you wish to have it immediately or just wait a couple of weeks for stable 4.2.