# CKEditor inline editing - adding hint text

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using the inline editing feature of CKEditor, but I want to add some hint text to the initial state of the control, i.e. something like "Click here to edit...", but I would like that hint text to be removed automatically when the user clicks the control to start typing. Is this feasible, or is there any alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a "placeholder" attribute on the element that you want to edit and add this plugin to your build of CKEditor: http://ckeditor.com/addon/confighelper

Comment: What of us who use `npm` in react?

Answer (score -1):

Your issue refers to:

- [ckEditor 4.1 - How do I remove inline tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771455/ckeditor-4-1-how-do-i-remove-inline-tooltip/15790093#15790093)
- [How to remove the "title" attribute that the CKEditor 4 add automatically on inline editing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730921/how-to-remove-the-title-attribute-that-the-ckeditor-4-add-automatically-on-inl)
- [How can I change the title ckeditor sets for inline instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502142/how-can-i-change-the-title-ckeditor-sets-for-inline-instances/14548739)
- [CKEditor forum post](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/How-to-remove-the-title-attribute-that-the-CKEditor-4-add-automatically-on-inline)

...and finally [the ticket](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10042) that will resolves above issues in the next major release (CKEditor 4.2).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken those refer to the title/tooltip attribute, not the placeholder